# Expression Engine Login problems

Tags: mysql, authentication, expressionengine

I have been able to do this for a while now but it seems to have stop all of a sudden.  Here goes:

When I login to expression engine at the backend - I cannot login to the front end with the same credentials - I get the following message:

MySQL ERROR:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Description: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

Query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count 
FROM exp_password_lockout 
WHERE 
  login_date > 1384272605 AND 
  ip_address = 'xx.xx.xx.xx' AND (
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/53' OR 
    username = 'admin' 
  )
```

The same thing happens visa versa (When I can login to the the front end but not the back end).

Please help

Comment: Did you checked if the table `exp_password_lockout` has the column `username`? The error says not.

Comment: no it doesnt should I had it in?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you sooooo much "DontVoteMeDown"

Comment: If you're querying a table is required that the fields you using have to be on that table. Do you want that I create an answer for that to be accepted ?

Comment: Have you forgot this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error below is known as [Bad Field Error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_bad_field_error):

> Unknown column '*%s*' in '*%s*'

So that means that some column refenced in the query was not found on any table of the same query. In order to reference a field in a SQL query, that field must be in a referenced table or the engine will throw that exception.

So double check if your table has that field, probably you'll realize that it does not.

I hope this helps.